# JQuery / Javascript issues with whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems with javascript not allowing my to use whitespace so I'm having to squash all the code making it hard to read.

```
Sample A: - Working:

output += '<li><a href="#">test here</a><li>';


Sample B: - Not Working:

output += '<li>
           <a href="#">test here</a>
           </li>';
```

Is there a way where I could get the above for work without having to first squash it all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a backspace:

```
output += '<li>\
           <a href="#">test here</a>\
           </li>';
```

**EDIT**
If you do want to keep the newlines, put `\n` before the `\`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this.  I find it slightly easier to read, but harder to maintain.

```
output += '<li>' + 
           '<a href="#">test here</a>' + 
           '</li>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out multi line strings in javascript.
Like so:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-multi-line-strings/

For some code example, try:

```
 output += '<li>\
               <a href="#">test here</a>\
               </li>'
```

Comment: @Brad: That's different. Backslash-newline does *not* produce a newline in the actual string; it is *only* a way to include a newline in the string-literal in the source-code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write markup in JS, unless it's just a couple of tags.

Consider creating elements in jQuery:

```
var output = $('<li>').append(
                $('<a>').attr('href', '#dalink')
            );
```

or much better, use [templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180582/templates-in-js), i.e. markup templates with placeholders and little presentational logic like loops for populating lists.

Comment: jQuery has it's good points and i use it religiously, but i find there are times when putting markup in is necessary.

Comment: @moonwave99, I think you mean `append`.  It could also be written `$('<li>').append($('<a>', {href: '#dalink'}))`.